# Flask : how to "fix" the static directory

Tags: python, flask

I have this issue with Flask when i try running this code with Flask :

```
@app.route('/viz')
def root():
  return render_template('page.html')
```

The file 'page.html' is in the templates folder, and contains some lines like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css">
```

But when I execute my program, the file doen't look for main.css in the static directory, but in the viz/static direcory ( /viz is the route of the view).

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a leading slash to tell the browser to use an absolute path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `static` folder within the package or next to your module. See the [Flask Quickstart documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files) for more details. Without knowing more about your structure, my guess is your tree should look something like this:

```
- top level directory (e.g. your package "root")
| app.py
| static/
| viz/
```